# Install button not visible in plugin manager in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to download some plugins via Manage Plugins in Jenkins but strangely I do not see any "Install without restart" or "Download now and install after restart" button at the bottom of the Plugin Manager in the web UI, hence I am not able to install any plugin. Need help to fix it.

[Image of the WebUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLpqf.png)

Jenkins version : 2.260

Can see below error in the logs :

Oct 06, 2020 5:52:57 PM WARNING hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler handleException
null
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.260.jar!/lib/layout/isAdmin.jelly:28:21: <d:invokeBody> java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Same in Jenkins 2.249.1 using jenkins/jenkins:lts docker image.

Comment: Same in Jenkins 2.249.1 using Bitnami AWS AMI

Comment: I am also experiencing this with Jenkins jenkins4eval/jenkins:2.250-alpine-arm64 docker image.

Answer (score 3):

There was an issue with the Jenkins update center which stands resolved. A plugin was added that had a dependency on itself.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63877

You might need to  click on "Check Now" to get rid of the cached local data and the install button should be visible.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked on Jenkins 2.249.1 using jenkins/jenkins:lts docker image but i needed to refresh the plugin list with "Check Now". Now the install buttons are back. Thanks @mayur-N

Answer (score 1):

it seems to depend on a broken JSON on https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json

**Workaround**: manually download and repair the JSON

```
curl https://updates.jenkins.io/current/update-center.json | sed -e 's/^{/'$(printf "\x1e")'{/' | jq --seq . > /var/lib/jenkins/update-center.json
```

set Update Site on Plugin Manager > Advanced > Update Site

```
URL file:///var/lib/jenkins/update-center.json
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this on jenkins4eval/jenkins:2.250-alpine-arm64 docker image.  Does this require a restart of jenkins?  I don't see a change to the UI after doing this

Comment: @CameronRosier you have triggered a "check now" on Plugin Manager > Advanced

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem ... different fresh systems (ami linux 2, ubuntu, ...). Same result. In jenkins manage plugins I don't see the "Install without restart" or "Download now and install after restart" button on bottom. :(

Other older installations has no problem.

Comment: Please, refrain from commenting in the answers section. Use the question's comments section or ask a question (separated post) explaining your situation.